# Is this a special case of FLT?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I heard that solving $$-x^6 + 3x^4y + 9x^4 - 7x^3 - 3x^2y^2 - 9x^2y - 18x^2 - 3xy^2 - 18xy + 27x + y^3 + 18y^2 + 54 = 0$$ in integers is possible by recognizing it as a special case of Fermat's last theorem. How can I find polynomials to represent it as a sum of $n$th powers ?

Comment: Fermat's theorem tells you that certain equations *don't* have roots, so I don't see how it could prove that this equation *does* have roots.

Comment: I guess one can write the equation to the form $P(x,y)^3+Q(x,y)^3-Z(x,y)^3=0$ for suitable polynomials and then solve the equations $P(x,y)=Q(x,y)=Z(x,y)=0$. But finding those polynomials is the hard task.

Comment: Ah...got it. Nice idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a bit fiddling one can find such polynomials.

The polynomials all have the same exponent, so let's make the reasonable assumption that it is $3$. Then at least one of the polynomials has an $x^2$ term. If we set $P_1(x,y)=-x^2+y+3$, then we are rid of all powers higher than $3$.

The next step is to assume that the other polynomials are of the form $P_i(x,y)=a_ix+b_iy+c_i$ for $i=2,3$. Then we try to solve the remaining equations that we get from equating coefficients.
Just trying out a few guesses (for example $a_2^3+a_3^3=-7$, so we try $a_2=-2$ and $a_3=1$) quickly leads to

$$P_1(x,y)=-x^2+y+3,\qquad P_2(x,y)=-2x+y,\qquad P_3(x,y)=x-y+3$$

and $\sum_iP_i(x,y)^3=0$ equals your expression.